# Data on Australian universities

Tags: data-request, education, australia

In the United States there's a great deal of information made public on universities, to help potential students, student loan recipients, employers, and whomever else to make informed decisions. Most of this is through the government and is accessible through financial aid information websites and other portals. For profit higher education requires greater reporting to be able to receive Federal student financial aid.

Is there anything like this for Australia?

I would like to know some of the test scores, GPA's, etc. associated with specific Australian universities.